# i cant open this "rosbag play airground_rig_s3_2013-03-18_21-38-48.bag" , i already download that file before run thats command

Tags: python, c++, ros

i try to use this source code "https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_svo_pro_open/blob/master/doc/frontend/visual_frontend.md".
i follow all the instruction until i run this command

```
roslaunch svo_ros run_from_bag.launch cam_name:=svo_test_pinhole
```

the RVIZ running although have some error message on terminal like this

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [svo_ros/svo_node]: Cannot locate node of type [svo_node] in package [svo_ros]. Make sure file exists in package path and permission is set to executable (chmod +x)
process[vis-3]: started with pid [12352]
process[svo_gui-4]: started with pid [12353]
RosPluginProvider.load(rqt_svo/Svo) exception raised in __builtin__.__import__(rqt_svo.svo, [Svo]):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rqt_gui/ros_plugin_provider.py", line 79, in load
    module = __builtin__.__import__(
  File "/home/lz/svo_ws/src/rpg_svo_pro_open/rqt_svo/src/rqt_svo/svo.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .svo_widget import SvoWidget
  File "/home/lz/svo_ws/src/rpg_svo_pro_open/rqt_svo/src/rqt_svo/svo_widget.py", line 9, in <module>
    from svo_msgs.msg import Info
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'svo_msgs'

PluginManager._load_plugin() could not load plugin "rqt_svo/Svo":
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/qt_gui/plugin_handler.py", line 102, in load
    self._load()
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/qt_gui/plugin_handler_direct.py", line 55, in _load
    self._plugin = self._plugin_provider.load(self._instance_id.plugin_id, self._context)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/qt_gui/composite_plugin_provider.py", line 72, in load
    instance = plugin_provider.load(plugin_id, plugin_context)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/qt_gui/composite_plugin_provider.py", line 72, in load
    instance = plugin_provider.load(plugin_id, plugin_context)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rqt_gui_py/ros_py_plugin_provider.py", line 61, in load
    return super(RosPyPluginProvider, self).load(plugin_id, plugin_context)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/qt_gui/composite_plugin_provider.py", line 72, in load
    instance = plugin_provider.load(plugin_id, plugin_context)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rqt_gui/ros_plugin_provider.py", line 90, in load
    raise e
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rqt_gui/ros_plugin_provider.py", line 79, in load
    module = __builtin__.__import__(
  File "/home/lz/svo_ws/src/rpg_svo_pro_open/rqt_svo/src/rqt_svo/svo.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .svo_widget import SvoWidget
  File "/home/lz/svo_ws/src/rpg_svo_pro_open/rqt_svo/src/rqt_svo/svo_widget.py", line 9, in <module>
    from svo_msgs.msg import Info
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'svo_msgs'

[svo_gui-4] process has died [pid 12353, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/noetic/lib/rqt_gui/rqt_gui -s rqt_svo.svo.Svo --args --topic svo __name:=svo_gui __log:=/home/lz/.ros/log/aa736034-c24b-11ed-b656-95c80644f063/svo_gui-4.log].
log file: /home/lz/.ros/log/aa736034-c24b-11ed-b656-95c80644f063/svo_gui-4*.log
```

The RVIZ didnt show any image when i run that code, and then i run this code

```
rosbag play airground_rig_s3_2013-03-18_21-38-48.bag
```

if i see on youtube after run this code the image will appear. but i got some error like this

```
[ INFO] [1678786760.716341956]: Opening airground_rig_s3_2013-03-18_21-38-48.bag
[FATAL] [1678786760.743528832]: Error opening file: airground_rig_s3_2013-03-18_21-38-48.bag
```

btw i use ros noetic when try this code

i hope someone can show me how to use this code cause i really need this for my academic project

thanks a lot to anyone who wants to help me :)

I want to be able to run this code as demonstrated

Comment: Did you check the first line? "Cannot locate node of type [svo_node] in package [svo_ros]. Make sure file exists in package"? Also I don't see any C++ related question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This is main errors:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [svo_ros/svo_node]: Cannot locate node of type [svo_node] in package [svo_ros]. Make sure file exists in package path and permission is set to executable (chmod +x)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'svo_msgs'
PluginManager._load_plugin() could not load plugin "rqt_svo/Svo":
```

I would guess something wrong with build process

It could be one of these problems:

- Workspace is not built
- `devel/setup.bash` is not sourced

Fix:

- Do a clean build by running `catkin clean` or/and delete `logs`, `devel`, `build` folder (basically only `src` is needed)
- Build it with `catkin_make` or `catkin build` (whichever you use in your workspace)
- Source by running `source devel/setup.bash`

But if problem is about execute permission

```
Make sure file exists in package path and permission is set to executable (chmod +x)
```

Because it's cpp file you need to search for it's built binary not the .cpp file. It should be located in `devel/lib/package_name/node_binary_name` so something like this:

```
sudo chmod +x devel/lib/svo_ros/svo_node  # Double check the path
```

Comment: thankyou sir it fixed after use catkin clean and rebuild the workspace